# Windows Apps | WinJS.Binding.as returns function in a string mode

Tags: string, function, binding, winjs

i got this script:

```js
 (function () {
    var app = WinJS.Application;
    WinJS.Namespace.define("Example", {
        randsFunction: WinJS.Binding.as ( {
         //Setting randNum to be returned from an anonymous function every second using setInterval.
            randNum:function(){
                var num = 0; setInterval(
                    function () {
                        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                    }, 1000)
                return num;
            }
        })
    });

    app.onactivated = function () {
// Now this is how we call the Example Namespace trying to replace the contents of the #myDiv (from the default.html) to a new value generated from randsFunction.

        Example.randsFunction.bind('randNum', function (value) {
                var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
                d.textContent = value;
        })
}

    app.start();

}());
```

When ran, the content inside the div prints:**function () {

           var num = 0; setInterval(
                 function () { 
               num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);  }, 1000)

               return num; 
           }**

It seems like `WinJS.Binding` cannot differentiate between a plain `string` and/or a `function`. Or what do you think is the problem? Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WinJS.Binding.as` only works against properties to produce an observable proxy.

It looks like you want to update a property on a timer and bind it to the `textContent` of an element.

You should create the observable proxy:

```js
WinJS.Namespace.define("Example", {
    bindSource: WinJS.Binding.as({
        num: 0 
    })
});
```

Bind it to your element:

```js
Example.bindSource.bind("num", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    d.textContent = newValue;
});
```

Then update the value through the observable proxy:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    Example.bindSource.num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}, 1000);
```

So your whole example would look something like this:

```js
(function () {
    var app = WinJS.Application;

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Example", {
        bindSource: WinJS.Binding.as({
            num: 0
        })
    });

    app.onactivated = function () {

        Example.bindSource.bind("num", function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
            d.textContent = value;
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            Example.bindSource.num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        }, 1000);
    }

    app.start();

}());
```

Hope that helps and you can see more examples of binding with WinJS at http://try.buildwinjs.com/#binding.